# Ansible - Play with hosts in order I desire

Tags: ansible

When running a playbook Ansible randomly sets a node as first, second and third.

```yaml
ok: [node-p02]
ok: [node-p03]
ok: [node-p01]
```

**Q:** How can I configure Ansible to let it execute with the hosts in sorted order? Example:

```yaml
ok: [node-p01]
ok: [node-p02]
ok: [node-p03]
```

`Serial: 1` is not an option, since it slows down the play, and my playbook is meant for 3 nodes in a single play.

Comment: any particular reason you have to run the nodes in order?

Comment: no real reason for this for sure, but if you do want, you can write your own stdout plugin, that will gather hosts' results for task, and print it at once in sorted order.

Comment: Maybe another execution strategy can help you: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_strategies.html#

Comment: Seems playbook strategies isn't gonna cut it. My playbook creates a Master / Slave / Slave configuration on the nodes. The Primary is set because it comes first. In my case it will be node-p02. But I desire it to be node-p01.

Comment: for me the reason is to upgrade the nomad leader last.  sorting is not an option since theres nothing in hostname/ip that identifies it as a leader, so ill have to just skip when it matches the ip, then run on that ip when its done with the rest.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Applicable for Ansible 2.4 and higher:

This is now the default behaviour, ansible will play the hosts in the *order* they were mentioned in the `inventory` file. Ansible also provides a few built in ways you can control it with `order`:

```
- hosts: all
  order: sorted
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

Possible values of `order` are:

- inventory: The default. The order is ‘as provided’ by the inventory
- reverse_inventory: As the name implies, this reverses the order ‘as provided’ by the inventory
- sorted: Hosts are alphabetically sorted by name
- reverse_sorted: Hosts are sorted by name in reverse alphabetical order
- shuffle: Hosts are randomly ordered each run

Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory

Comment: I'm seeing a random order by default on my inventory file, not "as provided", unfortunately.  using ansible 2.6.0, python 2.7.10.

Comment: Interesting, as per the docs it should still be defaulted to _inventory_ could it be that there is some other module/config in your repo which is messing it up?

Comment: There is a bug in ansible (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/44065) that can affect host ordering. It seems this is fixed only in ansible version 5. A this time the latest v4 release was 4.10 and that didn't include the fix.

Comment: June 2022, `ansible-core 2.12.4`: beware, "inventory order" does not mean "inventory file order". For instance, stuff in `host_wars` **prevail over the inventory file order**! Your can see the "real" inventory order with `ansible-inventory -i inventory.yml --list`

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:** The best solution is in [dubes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695393)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52146235/1990878) but this one gives you more freedom in case specific operations have to be applied to the host list, or you can't use Ansible 2.4.

Since Ansible 2.2 you can use `ansible_play_hosts` or `ansible_play_batch` and `sort` it:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | sort() }}"
```

From [ansible doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables):

> `ansible_play_hosts` is the full list of all hosts still active in the current play.
>
> `ansible_play_batch` is available as a list of hostnames that are in scope for the current ‘batch’ of the play. The batch size is defined by `serial`, when not set it is equivalent to the whole play (making it the same as `ansible_play_hosts`).

Answer (score 4):

I figured that another possibility is to use the exact hostnames in the `hosts` as a list, instead of a group. However, the other answers are more compliant to Ansible methods.

```yaml
---    
- hosts:
    - node-p01
    - node-p02
    - node-p03
```