# Sort IPs via Jinja2 template

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I am having an issue sorting IPs via Jinja2 and Ansible. Here are my variables and jinja2 code for ansible templates.

**roles/DNS/vars/main.yml:**

```
---
DC1:
   srv1:
     ip: 10.2.110.3
   srv2:
     ip: 10.2.110.11
   srv3:
     ip: 10.2.110.19
   srv4:
     ip: 10.2.110.24

DC2:
   srv5:
     ip: 172.26.158.3
   srv6:
     ip: 172.26.158.11
   srv7:
     ip: 172.26.158.19
   srv8:
     ip: 172.26.158.24
```

**roles/DNS/templates/db.example.com.j2:**

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN SOA                  example.com. root.example.com. (
                                2014051001  ; serial
                                      3600  ; refresh
                                      1800  ; retry
                                    604800  ; expire
                                     86400  ; minimum
)

; Name server
                       IN      NS      dns01.example.com.

; Name server A record
dns01.example.com.        IN      A       10.2.110.92


; 10.2.110.0/24 A records in this Domain
{% for hostname, dnsattr in DC1.iteritems() %}
{{hostname}}.example.com.   IN      A       {{dnsattr.ip}}


; 172.26.158.0/24 A records in this Domain
{% for hostname, dnsattr in DC2.iteritems() %}
{{hostname}}.example.com.   IN      A       {{dnsattr.ip}}
```

**roles/DNS/tasks/main.yml:**

```
- name: Update DNS zone file db.example.com 
  template: 
    src: db.example.com.j2
    dest: "/tmp/db.example.com"
  with_items: "{{DC1,DC2}}"

- name: Restart DNS Server
  service:
    name: named
    state: restarted
```

The DNS zone files get created correctly, but the IPs are not numerically sorted. I have tried using the following with no luck:

**Sorts on hostname alphabetically**

```
{% for hostname, dnsattr in center.iteritems() | sort %}
```

**Does not find the attribute dnsattr**

```
{% for hostname, dnsattr in center.iteritems() | sort(attribute='dnsattr.ip') %}
```

**Does not find the attribute ip**

```
{% for hostname, dnsattr in center.iteritems() | sort(attribute='ip') %}
```

Comment: `main.yml` is badly formatted – duplicate `ip` property, `db.example.com.j2` uses undefined `center` variable. And you state that _The DNS zone files get created correctly_. Really?

Comment: Hi Konstantin, Sorry. I pasted the main.yml data incorrectly in my post. I have edited the posted data to correctly reflect my dev environment. The sort issue still persists.

Comment: what about `center` variable in the template?

Comment: Another copy paste issue. The data and variables should be correct now.

Comment: can you refactor input data to be a list? `[{host: 'srv1',ip:'10.2.110.3'}, etc.]`?

Comment: You have two for loops in the template. Why do you need to use `with_items`  in the task ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any docs pointing this out, I just used logic to figure this out, after realizing a conversion back and forth between IP and int exists. 
(Note: method 1 works for me in Ansible 2.9.1, the docs say method 2 has worked since ansible 2.4.x)

Say we have 2 files: inventory.ini and playbook.yml

```
inventory.ini
[kube_nodes]
10.0.0.12
10.0.0.60
10.0.0.3

playbook.yml
---
- name: method 1
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Unsorted IP ordering
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ groups.kube_nodes }}"
  - name: Ascending IP ordering
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ groups.kube_nodes | list | ipaddr('int') | sort | ipaddr }}"
  - name: Decending IP ordering
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ groups.kube_nodes | list | ipaddr('int') | sort(reverse=true) | ipaddr }}"
```

Then we can use 
Bash# ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini

and see 
Unsorted IP ordering  = 10.0.0.12, 10.0.0.60, 10.0.0.3
Ascending IP ordering = 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.12, 10.0.0.60
Decendind IP ordering = 10.0.0.60, 10.0.0.12, 10.0.0.3

---

Alternatively, you may be able to make use of: specifying order of hosts at the play level:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users

```
- name: method 2
  hosts: all
  order: sorted #reverse_sorted, inventory, reverse_inventory, shuffle
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - debug: var=inventory_hostname
```

Comment: I also found this Q&A to be useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506865/ansible-play-with-hosts-in-order-i-desire
sm4rk0's answer that works in 2.2++ was particularly interesting to me.

Answer (score 1):

To have the IPs numerically sorted you could implement and use your own filter plugin (btw I'd be interested in any other solution):

In `ansible.cfg` add `filter_plugins = path/to/filter_plugins`.

In `path/to/filter_plugins/ip_filters.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def ip_sort(ip1, ip2):
    # Sort on the last number 
    return int(ip1.split('.')[-1]) - int(ip2.split('.')[-1])

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'sort_ip_filter': self.sort_ip_filter,
        }

    def sort_ip_filter(self, ip_list):
        return sorted(ip_list, cmp=ip_sort)
```

Then, in Ansible:

```
- name: "Sort ips"
  debug:
    msg: vars='{{ my_ips | sort_ip_filter }}'
```

---

I would also use the `ipaddr` filter to ensure the format is right:

```
- name: "Sort ips"
  debug:
    msg: vars='{{ my_ips | ipaddr | sort_ip_filter }}'
```

Comment: Thank you all! Great feedback.

Comment: Chris you are right, I do not need with_items since I am creating a single file. Konstantin I did change the format of my main.yml file to a list, and after doing, so I no longer need a sort function as the file is read in ascending order. Nicolas, I will try sorting my original main.yml file with your Jinja filter just to get some practice with creating and adding custom Jinja filters.