# sequential deployment in multiple servers using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have 8 servers as(s1,s2,s3...)which are windows servers and an ansible-playbook with tasks in roles. How do I configure host inventory and execute all these tasks in s1 then in s2 then in S3...sequentially that is the execution of the playbook in series of servers sequentially. I came across some terminology called serial but not sure on implementation The deployment will be carried using Jenkins. Any suggestions would be helpful Thanks in advance

I'm using ansible roles and the command I use is like this **ansible-playbook main.yml --tags 'build-job'**

Comment: Is that (one of) the documentation you are looking for ? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/guide_rolling_upgrade.html#the-rolling-upgrade

Comment: One of my stack friend suggested to put serial:1 in  play to execute plays host after host.
I was able to execute playbook in hosts one after the other.
I'm now facing a challenge, i have two hosts

`[webservers]
   host1
   host2`

the order of execution is from host2 and then to host1
not from host1 and then to host2.
Need guidance on this.

Comment: Please do not post essential info needed to understand your problem and give you a precise answer in volatile comments. Edit your question instead. And you should even change your title (example `how do I control the order of hosts execution when using serial: 1 on my playbook ?`). Unfortunately, this will then probably be tagged as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506865/ansible-play-with-hosts-in-order-i-desire)