# How to ensure groups list is sorted by inventory_hostname?

Tags: ansible

I have a role with this `vars/main.yml` file:

```
my_upstream: |
  upstream diagnos {
    server {{ groups.calldiag.0 }}.{{ cd_domain }}:4290 fail_timeout=300;
    server {{ groups.calldiag.1 }}.{{ cd_domain }}:4290 fail_timeout=300;
    ip_hash;
    keepalive 100;
  }
```

I use that variable in a file and everything works except my file has these lines:

```
  server x-demo-02.example.com:4290 fail_timeout=300;
  server x-demo-01.example.com:4290 fail_timeout=300;
```

I need it to be:

```
  server x-demo-01.example.com:4290 fail_timeout=300;
  server x-demo-02.example.com:4290 fail_timeout=300;
```

How can I make sure that `groups.calldiag.0` will be `x-demo-01` and that
`groups.calldiag.1` is `x-demo-02`?

I am not using inventory files.  I have my inventory and groups defined in AWX.

Comment: Are those the only two servers in the group? Are you supposed to include all servers in that file if you ever add more? Or will you always include the first two by lexical order only?

Comment: Could you just `sort()` them? See in example [Ansible - Play with hosts in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506865/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment, depending on your exact requirement, this example playbook should meet your expectations in both cases:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    cd_domain: example.com
    my_ustream_all: |-
      upstream diagnos {
        {% for h in groups.calldiag | sort -%}
        server {{ h }}.{{ cd_domain }}:4290 fail_timeout=300;
        {% endfor -%}
        ip_hash;
        keepalive 100;
      }
    my_ustream_two: |
      upstream diagnos {
        {% for h in (groups.calldiag | sort)[0:2] -%}
        server {{ h }}.{{ cd_domain }}:4290 fail_timeout=300;
        {% endfor -%}
        ip_hash;
        keepalive 100;
      }

  tasks:
    - name: Show line by line content for all servers scenario
      debug:
        var: my_ustream_all.splitlines()

    - name: Show line by line content for only two first servers scenario
      debug:
        var: my_ustream_two.splitlines()
```

I created the following inventory to test:

```yaml
---
calldiag:
  hosts:
    x-demo-04:
    x-demo-02:
    x-demo-03:
    x-demo-01:
```

And the result gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show line by line content for all servers scenario] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_ustream_all.splitlines()": [
        "upstream diagnos {",
        "  server x-demo-01.example.com:4290 fail_timeout=300;",
        "  server x-demo-02.example.com:4290 fail_timeout=300;",
        "  server x-demo-03.example.com:4290 fail_timeout=300;",
        "  server x-demo-04.example.com:4290 fail_timeout=300;",
        "  ip_hash;",
        "  keepalive 100;",
        "}"
    ]
}

TASK [Show line by line content for only two first servers scenario] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_ustream_two.splitlines()": [
        "upstream diagnos {",
        "  server x-demo-01.example.com:4290 fail_timeout=300;",
        "  server x-demo-02.example.com:4290 fail_timeout=300;",
        "  ip_hash;",
        "  keepalive 100;",
        "}"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```